# How to get a single response from firestore (as a future) and dynamic from Api's ( as a stream)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, stream, future

Method to get ids from firestore and on that id fetch data from Server (through API):

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> fetchingData() async {
var decodeData;
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('signals').get()
    .then((value) {
  for (var element in value.docs) {
    firstoreIds.add(element.get('id'));
    //  print('firestore ids: ${element.get('id')}');
  }
}).whenComplete(() async{
  for (var element in firstoreIds){
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(basicUrl + element + remainingUrl));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      decodeData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      // print('value... ${SingleCoin.fromJson(decodeData)}');
      // return SingleCoin.fromJson(decodeData);
      print('\n\n\nresponse body: ${decodeData}');
      return decodeData;
    } else {

      throw Exception('error occurred in apis');
    }
  }
});
print('decode data: $decodeData');
}
```

Now I got id from firestore and pass that id to the API URL and it got the exact same coin data, but I am confused about how to show this response on the screen. There is also some data from firestore which I want it to be as a Future response and some data come from server(through API) that I want it to be dynamic(Stream).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: check `Stream.asyncMap` method

Comment: Frank got it, thanks for the edit

Comment: I apply Stream.asyncMap but it doesn't work for me, because I want half of data from firestore and the remaining data from API and want to show it in a card, and from firestore there is also id, on the basis of which I want to get specific coin from api.